# Need help in pipoint new server performance hit

Tags: nginx, openresty

I recently moved from OVH to Hetzner server, in my `Nginx` logs I started to see that the cache hit became very slow in the p99, in my former server I had on p99 ~60ms for the request, in the current server it becomes ~600ms.

The changes I made:

1. Ovh runs `Openrety` and Hetzner runs `Nginx` (they both should be the same since `Openresty` is `Nginx` fork with additional functionality, I expect that `Nginx` will perform better than `Openresty`)
2. in Ovh I had an Intel-based server, now in Hetzner is AMD based server (with much more RAM and CPU power)

I thought I should start in disk performance (they both should be Nvme), but before I would like to get suggestions on where should I start and how to prevent such degradation in future updates/server changes.

-------------- edit --------------------

This is my disk perf:

```
iozone -t1 -i0 -i2 -r1k -s1g /tmp
        Iozone: Performance Test of File I/O
                Version $Revision: 3.489 $
                Compiled for 64 bit mode.
                Build: linux-AMD64

        Contributors:William Norcott, Don Capps, Isom Crawford, Kirby Collins
                     Al Slater, Scott Rhine, Mike Wisner, Ken Goss
                     Steve Landherr, Brad Smith, Mark Kelly, Dr. Alain CYR,
                     Randy Dunlap, Mark Montague, Dan Million, Gavin Brebner,
                     Jean-Marc Zucconi, Jeff Blomberg, Benny Halevy, Dave Boone,
                     Erik Habbinga, Kris Strecker, Walter Wong, Joshua Root,
                     Fabrice Bacchella, Zhenghua Xue, Qin Li, Darren Sawyer,
                     Vangel Bojaxhi, Ben England, Vikentsi Lapa,
                     Alexey Skidanov, Sudhir Kumar.

        Run began: Sat Mar 30 21:31:27 2024

        Record Size 1 kB
        File size set to 1048576 kB
        Command line used: iozone -t1 -i0 -i2 -r1k -s1g /tmp
        Output is in kBytes/sec
        Time Resolution = 0.000001 seconds.
        Processor cache size set to 1024 kBytes.
        Processor cache line size set to 32 bytes.
        File stride size set to 17 * record size.
        Throughput test with 1 process
        Each process writes a 1048576 kByte file in 1 kByte records

        Children see throughput for  1 initial writers  = 1357142.88 kB/sec
        Parent sees throughput for  1 initial writers   =  917385.44 kB/sec
        Min throughput per process                      = 1357142.88 kB/sec
        Max throughput per process                      = 1357142.88 kB/sec
        Avg throughput per process                      = 1357142.88 kB/sec
        Min xfer                                        = 1048576.00 kB

        Children see throughput for  1 rewriters        = 2778509.50 kB/sec
        Parent sees throughput for  1 rewriters         = 1344902.22 kB/sec
        Min throughput per process                      = 2778509.50 kB/sec
        Max throughput per process                      = 2778509.50 kB/sec
        Avg throughput per process                      = 2778509.50 kB/sec
        Min xfer                                        = 1048576.00 kB

        Children see throughput for 1 random readers    = 2124835.00 kB/sec
        Parent sees throughput for 1 random readers     = 2120469.60 kB/sec
        Min throughput per process                      = 2124835.00 kB/sec
        Max throughput per process                      = 2124835.00 kB/sec
        Avg throughput per process                      = 2124835.00 kB/sec
        Min xfer                                        = 1048576.00 kB

        Children see throughput for 1 random writers    = 1484397.88 kB/sec
        Parent sees throughput for 1 random writers     =  919064.98 kB/sec
        Min throughput per process                      = 1484397.88 kB/sec
        Max throughput per process                      = 1484397.88 kB/sec
        Avg throughput per process                      = 1484397.88 kB/sec
        Min xfer                                        = 1048576.00 kB
```

This is my disk layout:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            13G  2.7M   13G   1% /run
/dev/md2        1.8T  286G  1.5T  15% /
....
```

I'm not sure why I get this high p99 cache fetch on this server :(